# Java implementing multiple threads (excel processing)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

So my application allows the user to select Microsoft excel file(s), usually having between 300 to 5000 rows. At times even larger than 5000. My question is would it be more efficient to use multiple threads in this scenario and what is the most effective way to then utilize the threads. Should each file have a thread of its own or what ? Also this is how each excel file is processed:

```
  Load file
  loop until eof
   iterate through rows and cells
   Assign each cell to variable x  
   concatenate required chars to begin and end of x
   Append x to y
  End loop

  Write y to text file
```

**EDIT CODE**

```
 public class FileParse implements Callable<String>
 {

private String fPath;
private BufferedReader br;
private String line;

@Override
public String call()
{
line = "";
try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fPath));

        String sCurrentLine = "";

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            line += sCurrentLine;

        }
    }catch(IOException exc){
        System.out.println("Cant load file");

    }


return line;
}


public FileParse (String location)
{
    br = null;
    fPath = location;

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Callable<String> t1 = new FileParse("rsrc\\data12.txt");
    Callable<String> t2 = new FileParse("rsrc\\data13.txt");    

    Future<String> fut1 = executor.submit(t1);
    Future<String> fut2 = executor.submit(t2);


    try{

    System.out.println(fut1.get());
    System.out.println(fut2.get());
    }catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException e){

    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be quicker to use multiple threads, yeah. One thread per file sounds good, but you still need some sort of limit (too many threads will bring a lot of problems).

My suggestion you experiment with [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), and implement [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and send in Runnables for it to run. It will automatically assign the new Runnables you send in to a `Thread` when it becomes available.

You can start an `ExecutorService` with a fixed number of threads simply by calling `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int numThreads)`. Then just call `submit(Runnable runnableWithYourProcessing)`. Don't forget to `shutdown()` when you're done!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows:

- Define a Task class that implements `Callable` interface and returns a `String`
- The task class would work on a row with given index.
- Create an `ExecutorService` with fixed number of threads and submit Task instances for each row in the excel sheet.
- The `Future<String>`returned by the `Callable`s are collected and the values are concatenated to get the result.

Comment: I kind of understand your approach but why work with given index rather than individual files ? Because I forgot to mention this but each excel file has an individual txt file output. So if user loads `test1.xlsx test2.xlsx` then the program will output `test1.txt test2.txt`

Comment: in other words would it not be more appropriate if each task instance took a file path and processed it rather than taking an individual row at a time ?

Comment: It all boils down to the degree of parallelism. One could have each task work on a line, then an enclosing task working on a file and the main method will spawn as many enclosing task as the number files, keeping in mind the memory requirements, @user1477957.

Comment: for example look at edited question.Am i on the right track with the multi-threading ? I'm a bit confused with how it works